# link in ajax generated text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a search field witch generates a list of users through ajax/jquery.

Result:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
    <span class="badge addUserToGroup" data-user="{{ user.getId }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Add</span>
    {{ user.getUsername }} <br />
    {{ user.getEmail }}
</li>
```

I am now going to add a user from my search result to a group by clicking on the . But nothing happens. When I'm looking at the sours I can't see the search result (off course since it's not loaded until later). But how do I target a span which is not visible in the source?

This simple test for clarity. The function below is never triggered.

```
$(".addUserToGroup").click(function() {

    alert('Hello World');

});
```

What do I do?

Comment: did you wrapped your code into `$(document).ready(function() { .. })`? Otherwise it would not be initialized right.
Edit: or hook the function into the `done()` callback of your ajax request.
Anyway, the function need to be correctly initialized.

Comment: When you add a dynamic content, in your case your search results you need to bind the event on the `body` and specify the dynamic selector you will use, like in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change you jQuery a little bit and it will attach your click handler to dynamic elements.

```
$('body').on('click', ".addUserToGroup", function() {

    alert('Hello World');

});
```

Comment: How do I get the element i clicked on? $(this) will refer to body in this case.

Comment: `$(this)` should be the element that has been clicked. See this bin https://jsbin.com/liladuviga/edit?html,js,output